# why does Scrapy CrawlSpider rules not work ?it just crawl the start url page

Tags: scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl a site, it has no errors,but it just crawl the start url page, not follow the rules and continue down .I am sure that start url has next link
 match "/plc.*" and the setting is default
please see the code:

```
class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Test'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

headers = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8',
}

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/gsx.*"), callback="parse_item", process_request="test"),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/plc.*'), follow=True, process_request="test"),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/pla.*'), follow=True, process_request="test"),
)


def start_requests(self):
    yield Request("http://www.example.com/login.json", meta = {'cookiejar' : 1}, headers=self.headers, callback=self.post_login)

def post_login(self, response):
    print 'Preparing login'
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                        meta = {'cookiejar' : 1},
                        headers = self.headers,
                        formdata = {
                        'account': 'test',
                        'password': 'test',
                        'redirect': 'http://www.example.com/',
                        'remember' : 'true'
                        },
                        callback = self.after_login
                        )]

def after_login(self, response):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, meta = {'cookiejar' : 1}, headers = self.headers)


def test(self, request):
    return Request(request.url, meta={'cookiejar':1}, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):
    print response.url
    logging.info('URL:%s' %response.url)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5))
```

Comment: my be i should return item in the parse_item. I'm gonna try these on

Comment: I have the same issue. I don't think it will work cause I tried it...Please let me know if you solved it. I have been stuck on this for days -_-